# autoconf & automake versus -O2 versus -O3

Tags: autoconf, automake

My configure.ac contains

```
AC_PROG_CXX
```

and my Makefile.am contains

```
AM_CXXFLAGS= -Werror -O3
```

and the resulting 'configure' script keeps on adding -O2 to the mix in addition to O3.

I have this suspicion that I'm supposed to do something in configure.ac to declare my preference for O3, but I can't find it in the doc. How do I tell it that I want to control the optimization level?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you are not supposed to add anything to configure.ac to indicate a preference for -O3.  That sort of thing belongs in a user's CONFIG_SITE, not in configure.ac

However, if you insist on breaking the convention, you can do something like:

```
: ${CXXFLAGS=-Werror -O3}
```

Note that this line must appear before AC_PROG_CXX (or any macro that AC_REQUIRES it, such as LT_INIT, as that will cause AC_PROG_CXX to be emitted into the configure script before this line.)

Comment: I don't get it. I've got a program that is carefully written to be safe with, and benefit from, maximal optimization. There's no way to express this?

Comment: The user expects -g -O2 to be used if no preference is specified.  It is the user's prerogative to modify CXXFLAGS, not the package maintainer's.  It is okay to add -Werror to AM_CXXFLAGS, but the optimization level must be left for the user to select.

Comment: Caveat on that last comment.  You should only add -Werror to AM_CXXFLAGS if you check during the configury that CXX accepts that option.  Not all compilers do, and the user will be very annoyed when the build fails for a compiler that doesn't accept the option.

Comment: sigh. I just want to change the default and leave it to the user to ask for what they want if they disagree.

Comment: The snippet above should do that, and it's probably okay, but there are some users who will complain vociferously and it is not considered best practice.  You can always specify the flags in your package control files (debian/rules or *.spec)

Comment: OK, this code will never be a debian package. It's on github, and a few people will use it, but they are the sort of people who won't whine about this. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @WilliamPursell: I never build autoconfiscated packages with `-Werror`. I find that it often confuses a number of tests, where a compiler warning has been misinterpreted as the absence of a header or an unsupported feature.

Comment: CXXFLAGS is a plain environment variable that the user can set, for example in Bourne shell: export CXXFLAGS=-O3, then ./configure, when you type make, you will see the -O3 in every compile line

Answer (score 4):

The prior answer is correct in that it should be the installer's choice what flags are used.  If you're still wondering where the -g -O2 comes from (likely), it is described at http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/autoconf/C_002b_002b-Compiler.html.

That page does suggest "If your package does not like this default, then it is acceptable to insert the line ‘: ${CXXFLAGS=""}’ after AC_INIT and before AC_PROG_CXX to select an empty default instead."